# How to beat morning blues

Tags: health

It is always very hard to wake up in the morning make up to the work.

How to overcome this issue?

I am mostly late to office.

What to do to overcome this?

I should not take tea or coffee as I have health issue.

My body is so tired.

I am sleeping for 7-8 hours per day but still I am facing this issue over a long period of time.

Comment: Have you had your hormones checked to rule out an issue with your thyroid? You have to request this test from the doctor; it is not a standard test they issue regularly.

Comment: @Laura “They” are presumably country-dependent.

Comment: Have you been to a doctor about the issue?

Comment: I would say dance and MUSIC seems to solve this for me. Getting up and playing my favourite tunes gets me going :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not a solution, but I think these can help:

1. Eat an apple. It's been proved that eating an apple in the morning has the same or similar effect as drinking a coffee. Never tried it, but I guess it's worth a try.
2. Try to always shower in the morning. If you are already taking the shower, remember to end it with 10-20 secs of cold water...
3. If you drive to work, try having the window down, this way, fresh air will wake you up.
4. Listen to news, instead of music, or as an extra if you don't listen to anything. The news will get your attentions making your brain busy.

Maybe something of the above will work for you. Good luck!

Comment: By #3 are you encouraging a sleepy person to drive a vehicle in order to wake up? That seems to be a reckless and dangerous method to use, not only for yourself but also for others. That doesn't seem helpful to me.

Comment: I can attest to eating an apple as very effective waking you up. It's almost as fast as drinking a glass of lemon juice thinking it was orange juice.

Comment: @Stan I'm just assuming that this person NEEDS to drive, like many other persons that can't choose any other way to go to work

Comment: @MarioGarcia 3) 'fresh air'... depends on where you live, in FL summer, you'll get 95F air with 95% humidity... not exactly reviving.

Answer (score 1):

Do breathing gymnastic after waking up on a fresh air. Your brain will receive a necessary portion of oxygen so it will help you to wake up.
Also avoid lying around after waking up. Develop a habit to stand up and start doing your morning routine at once after you wake up. 
And try to go to bed in the period from 10pm to 1am, because this time is very important.

Answer (score 1):

Change your lightbulbs.

Using bright lighting of a bluer hue can help you wake up in the morning (or at any time). [Here's one of many articles on the subject](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/03/190306100602.htm).

I use 5000 Kelvin bulbs in my home (you could also try 4000K). When I turn on these lights in the morning, there is a very distinct effect of making me more alert.

There are bulbs which work with various home automation hubs [which can be tuned to different temperatures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N9H9IAP) (tones). iOS added NightShift a few years ago which changes the overall tone of your phone to a lower (yellower) tone in the evening. This was to minimize the use of you phone inadvertently keeping you awake, not just because it's "easier on your eyes". There are [products available](https://www.usa.philips.com/c-p/HF3429_60/golite-blu-energy-light) for using blue light to help mood and wakefulness. Searching for `blue light helps you wake up` will turn up a plethora of articles and papers on the subject.

It's worth a shot. You should be able to find a 4 pack of cheap 5000K LED bulbs online for less that $10. Or buy a pack from Costco and return them if they don't help.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

One thing: move, shake, stretch and breath deeply while brushing your teeth and make that the first thing in the morning. You will be awake and motivated in an instant.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer you may also consider:

- Eating a wholesome breakfast rich in vitamin C.
- Opening the window and exposing youself to the sunlight for a few minutes.
- Doing some warm-up exercises. [This may sound counterintuitive but exercises (in combination with good nutrition) actually boost you energy.] You don't need an hour and a half program - 10 minutes may be just enough.

[There are many reasons why you may feel tired despite getting appropriate amount sleeping.  For example, not being able to sleep well due to the surrounding environment, that is, noise, light, heat, cold, etc. (just because you are getting enough quantity of sleep doesn't mean you've slept well and are thus rested); lack of nutrients (not eating well or enough will make you feel tired and generally unwell); depression (people with depression tend to feel tired all of the time); illness or some medical condition; medication (some medication could make you feel tired or affect your sleep); alcohol (alcohol consumption may affect the quality of your sleep); etc. If you are feeling tired all of the time (I couldn't tell if that is the case from your question) it may be related to your lifestyle in general. It is important to find out the reason for your tiredness and address it accordingly.]

Answer (score 0):

## Wake up for something other than work

I used to do the:

Wake up for work>Get ready for work>Drive to work>Work

Process and would always feel tired, I'd resent waking up and be slow getting ready because the end reward of the process was work...not something that thrills most of us.

What you wake up for is up to you, whether you enjoy a run, reading, puzzle solving or pottering around in the garden its your motivation (though I'd recommend something you're involved with, not a passive task like watching tv). Get up for that, get dressed and showered so you can do that and you'll find yourself more with it when you do get to work.

This does mean waking up a little earlier which may be difficult to do at first since you know you can do those things once you're home from work too. Routine, however, is the essential part of this - once you keep the routine up you'll find your body adapts and your approach to waking up changes too.

Answer (score 0):

"Morning blues" can be caused by a variety of reasons. You should not fight the "blues", but the causes.

1. Have your health checked, at least the basic stuff, which can prevent you for having a good quality sleep.
2. If the job is the cause of stressful life = bad sleep, you need to improve something about your job. (been there, done that)
3. Increase the "intake" of fresh vegetables (most likely salads) and fruits.
4. Increase the "intake" of seeds (nus, sun-flower seeds, pumpkin seeds etc.)
5. Avoid sugar in all forms, including off-the-shelf juices, chocolate... It gives you a temporary boost, at the cost of draining your energy for the rest of the day. (been there, done that)
6. Exercise - whatever you enjoy: gym, jogging, riding the bicycle, physical sports...
7. Visit parks/ forests if they are anywhere close to you - supplement of fresh oxygen.
8. Refresh the air in the bedroom before going to sleep.
9. Shower before going to bed. My personal experience (strange but it works): I apply cold water (the coldest available at the tap, nothing hight tech) on arms and legs. After that, I sleep like a baby.
10. Shower after you wake up - the minimum benefit is the physical exercise.
11. Go to bed earlier.

About 3 and 4, I cannot give you yet many details, I am still experimenting. I generally prepare fresh salads with beet-root, carrots and apples. Additionally I add whatever I have available: mushrooms, celery (roots/leaves), lettuce, pears... Be careful that some vegetables MUST BE TREATED thermally (boiled, grilled) - otherwise they are toxic - e.g. the egg-plant.

Additionally, you may use some supplements of vitamins (C, D) and minerals (Ca, Mg). Black/blue, red and yellow / orange vegetables / fruits are the richest in nutrients.

Avoid (at least temporarily, as a test) meat. And alcohol, if it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Set a light-bulb to turn on automatically before you wake up. Humans are designed to wake up naturally with Sunlight, so you want to simulate that by getting a high color temperature bulb (5000k+) and setting it up with a timer so that the light turns on 1/2 hour before your actual alarm goes off. This will signal your body it's time to wake up naturally so that by the time your alarm does go off, your body will be ready.

I have a lamp pointed at the ceiling which automatically turns on everyday. This produces a natural lighting effect at the same time everyday without harsh light in my eyes.

[image: Lamp]
Behold the Sun! 
(Source: Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Lamp#/media/File:Free_standing_lamp.jpg)

You also want to listen to your bodies natural sleep cycle, so try to sleep in multiples  of 90 minutes. Go to bed at the same time every night and then use a phone app to detect your sleep cycles.